# Auto-removal of comments like "Possible duplicate of..." upon closing a question: How does it work?

Tags: support, comments

I just noticed that a "Possible duplicate of..." comment at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89421/if-i-want-to-be-a-normal-vampire-how-can-i-become-it-if-i-am-a-werewolf was automatically removed after I cast the last closing vote on it. I understand that this is to avoid redundancy, as the question will be automatically edited to include questions that it is a possible duplicate of, anyway.

However, my comment, "Also a possible duplicate of [How exactly does lycanthropy work?  Does it mix with vampirism?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34905/how-exactly-does-lycanthropy-work-does-it-mix-with-vampirism)" wasn't auto-removed.

How does the auto-removal of these comments work? Do the comments have to follow a certain format so that they will get deleted? What other types of comments get an auto-delete?

Answer (score 8):

I think only the auto-generated comments get auto-deleted.  If you add another one manually, it will persist.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that 'possible duplicate of..." comments are (or could be) auto-generated. Can anyone point me to where I can read more about what types of comments are auto-generated and auto-deleted?

Comment: I have never seen one auto-generated, they always seem to have a username next to it. Ex: possible duplicate of ... - jeffreylin

Comment: @JeffreyLin Those are auto-generated.  They are automatically added when a person casts the first VTC as duplicate.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I think it might just delete comments with links to the dupe actually, I've seen custom comments deleted. They may have been edited from the original custom comment though, not sure.